# Automatically update references to other headings on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been searching around for quite a while on ways to do this, and I'm beginning to think it's not doable.  I can't say I'm an expert in html or CSS, but I have done a lot of research and found no tutorial for this specific problem.

I am coding a software user's guide to be posted online.  The guide will include screenshots of the software, with figure numbers.  The original code (I'm not the first on this project) simply hardcodes in the numbers of each image, which becomes more and more tedious as more information is added in.

I know there is a way to simply add in a new image and then tag the caption to include an automatically incrementing figure number. This would be very helpful, for if a new figure is added in, the numbers automatically change in all of the figures after the new one.

IF that were the only facet of the problem, I would simply use a CSS counter and be done with it.  However, I also want to be able to reference specific figures in the text of the guide.  My question is this:  Is there a way to do this in CSS?

An example of text within the guide would be "**Figure n** shows the dialog box for customizing x."  Is there a way to reference the nth figure in the guide without hardcoding the numbers?

If this is not possible in CSS, is there another language that can do it?

**Edit:**  To clarify:  The figures themselves would be labeled consecutively.  But if I wanted to, within my text, refer to Figure 3, for example, that could be anywhere.

**Edit 2:**  I have tried a javascript implementation using arrays.  However, now it seems that some versions of Internet Explorer refuse to show the script portions of my code.

I am using the `<script></script>` tags within the body of my document, calling a javascript function located in the head.  I know the syntax must be right because firefox and google chrome both load the page just fine.  Is this simply IE being picky about something?  (I checked, it's not my security settings).

Comment: Will they always have a consistent relationship between the elements? For example, will references to `figure 1` *always* appear before `figure 2`? Or will there (likely) be references to `figure 1` at random places throughout the document?

Comment: Yes, there could be references to the figures anywhere within the document.

Comment: Yes, but after figure 1, it will always be figure 2 and then 3..?

Comment: I think JavaScript is the only solution, but you'd have to specify, somehow, which image/`figure` you want to refer to. Probably via an element `id`, or some other attribute, that's unique.

Comment: ^^ Yes, I would suggest Javascript as well - make a global array, and when you generate the page, each time you encounter something you want to refer back to, push it into the array. Then each time you want to refer to it, use Javascript to generate the identifier you want. You will have to generate the full array before referring to it.

Comment: Sounds like I'll need a separate name for each figure after all.  Thank you for the quick answers; this should definitely speed up the process of cleaning up this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is, referring to things by their page index (incrementing) and by some figure number you maintain (also incrementing) are **two identical solutions**.

Actual problem: Maintaining the figure list with a sequence of ordered numeric identifiers becomes more difficult the longer a document becomes.

Solution: Give figures names, not numbers, and generate a number for display to the user. This gives ordered numbering to the user and allows you to reference figures with memorable names, but does not require you to reorder or modify figure numbers after every edit. Here's a quick example using jQuery:

```
<h2>How to add a contact</h2>
<img id="add-contact" class="figure" src="figures/add-contact.png" />
<p><a href="#add-contact">This screenshot</a> shows the location of the Add Contact button.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     var figNum = 0;
     $(".figure").each(function() {
       figNum++;
       $("a[href='#"+$(this).attr("id")+"']").append(" (figure "+figNum+")");
     });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I see.  This makes it a matter of focusing on the figures themselves, and allowing the numbering to follow as a consequence.  So, I believe this is saying that the best thing I can do here is to make sure each figure has a meaningful name, and call back to the _name_ instead of focusing on the number?